# I want to run two nuxt.js(vue.js) apps on one server. (pm2)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, pm2, nuxt.js

Start nuxt.js like this:

`vue init nuxt/express myapp1`

`vue init nuxt/express myapp2`

My structure is as follows.

`/workspace/myapp1 (nuxt.js app)`

`/workspace/myapp2 (nuxt.js app)`

In my workspace there are myapp1 and myapp2.

When you start one app,

I ran the app at pm2 start npm - start in / workspace / myapp1.

**But what if I run two apps?**

Answer (score 1):

You can start both apps on different ports (i.e. myapp1 on port 3030 and myapp2 on port 3031) and use nginx as a [reverse proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/).

Also see
 [How To Set Up a Node.js Application for Production on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04) which gives a great overview how to set up nodejs+pm2+nginx on production environment.

Comment: How to check what app is running on which port?